# Method to identify the point in which the slope of a predicted probability becomes significant

Tags: r, regression, logistic, regression-coefficients

I'm running a logistic regression in which I'm predicted a binary response from a continuous predictor... I'm interested in determining the exact point in which the predicted probability `(exponentiated y-hat / (1 + exponentiated y-hat)` becomes significantly different than the average y-hat (or average predicted probability of the discrete event...

I was thinking of some sort of Johnson Neyman technique, but am unsure how to begin this exercise...

Would like to do this in `R` at the end of the day, but not required for an answer.

Comment: "I'm interested in determining the exact point in which the predicted probability" are you saying that you are seeking, by way of sequential analysis, the necessary sample size to show that, according to the mean model, you may obtain confidence intervals for any one mean value of $Y$ at a given $X$ for which $E[Y|X]$ is significantly different from $\bar{Y}$ as a general test of hetereogeneity?

Comment: Hmmm, that might be one way to do that... I'm saying i'd like to determine at what value of x does the predicted probability of y become statistically different than the mean predicted probability of y...not necessarily a sample size issue, however.

Comment: This isn't really clear. If there is an effect of X in the linear predictor, then there is a difference between any 2 points along X. Whether such a difference would be 'significant' only depends on how far apart they are & on N, but any 'non-significant' difference would just be a type II error.

Comment: So really, at what point does the slope for my given effect become statistically different than 0... That might be another way to think about it.

Comment: @gh0strider18 this might be a little highfalutin but if you consider your data to be sampled in arrays of row indpendent data, it's never exactly clear what order the data come in. The number you are describing could be 5, if it is only necessary to restrict to a subset of 5 observations to attain a statistically significant logit slope. Alternately, it could be 100 *in the same sample* depending upon which observations, exactly, you add.

Comment: @gh0strider18 I think it may be useful for you to become familiarized with resampling based statistics, particularly the bootstrap, jackknife, and k-fold cross validation as different ways of addressing the issue of error estimation for parameters and combinations or subsets of the sample and their impact on inference.

Comment: why would a Mann-Kendall-like resampling not give you a CI?  You can then compare CI with actual to look for outliers.

Answer (score 1):

A logit model is a linearization of a nonlinear relationship between the X's and the dichotomous outcome. The slope is therefore constant everywhere in X.

As far as the predicted probabilities, the average predicted probability is just the proportion of 1's in your data. So you want to identify for what value of X does an observation have a higher probability of being 1 than the overall proportion. You can do that a number of ways - one way would be to estimate the predicted probabilities for each level of X (keeping other variables in your model at their means), sort them and see at which point is it higher than the overall. (You can find this out by looking at the coefficients and doing some arithmetic, but this may be easier if you have trouble with converting log-odds to p).

You can also estimate a confidence interval around the marginal effect (i.e. average probability) at each level. I haven't done this in R though it probably isn't that complicated - in Stata, you run your logit and then do margins. For example, I simulated some data where the overall sample probability is 0.391, and one standard normal predictor x, where the true logit coefficient was 2. In Stata, here is my output:

```
    logit y x

Logistic regression                               Number of obs   =       1000
                                                  LR chi2(1)      =     504.19
                                                  Prob > chi2     =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -417.09877                       Pseudo R2       =     0.3767

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   2.192613   .1399275    15.67   0.000      1.91836    2.466866
       _cons |  -.8138537   .0933571    -8.72   0.000    -.9968302   -.6308772

margins

             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |       .391   .0116073    33.69   0.000     .3682501    .4137499
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

margins, at(x==0.2)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   .4072535    .020886    19.50   0.000     .3663176    .4481893
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Look at the confidence intervals for the two margins commands and you will see that they overlap, so even though at x=0.2 you see a predicted probability higher than the average, it isn't statistically significant.

**EDIT**: Per whuber's comments below, this approach doesn't account for the sampling variation of the mean from the data. It will tell you a difference from a particular value, which may happen in this instance to be the mean of your sample. But it may not address your specific question.

Comment: There are some delicate issues here. After all, the mean of the data is itself a random variable, as are the fitted coefficients and any "predicted probability," and these of course are all based on the same random dataset. It is not apparent that your proposal handles these complications correctly. In fact, it's not evident what the question even means, since "significantly different" implies a *hypothesis test.* What is the null hypothesis you are testing and what is its alternative?

Comment: I took OP's question to mean how to find the value of X where the predicted probability would be a statistically significant from the average predicted probability in the dataset. I understood the hypothesis test to whether the predicted probability at X=x is statistically different from the mean. However, I agree with you that the average is a sample average, so must be treated as a statistic not a parameter. How would you propose adjusting my approach to account for the sampling variability?

Comment: Your attempt at a null hypothesis does not appear valid for two reasons: (1) it refers to the data rather than the actual state of affairs and (2) it refers to a value $x$ that is supposed to be determined from the data themselves! Now *if* $x$ were specified in advance, a hypothesis of the form "the predicted value at $x$ differs from the mean" would work--but it doesn't seem possible to couch the question in this form. It might be more fruitful to think of the question as requesting some form of *interval estimate* (which will cover values of $X$).

Comment: That makes sense, and perhaps that's what the OP was trying to get at - maybe he/she didn't really mean statistical significance per se. On a related note, I will say that in psychometrics I have seen statisticians compare two scores to determine if, based on the sample of items used, they are statistically different. Would you say in that case again it is an incorrect use of the terms? If so, what would you recommend instead? It seems to me the OP is doing something similar.

Comment: In the situation you cite, if I understand it correctly, there is a null hypothesis that can be tested: $H_0$ is that the underlying values reflected by the scores are equal and $H_A$ is that they are unequal. The difference here is that the OP describes a kind of *search* for a threshold. It asks for an *estimate* of some sort to be constructed from the data. It is common for people to misuse statistical language, so one of the first things we want to do here on CV is try to understand and usefully frame the underlying question in a mutually comprehensible language, and only then answer it.